# How do I seperate the label and field in twig forms?

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to be able to apply some bootstrap formatting on these fields and labels but I don't want all the fields displayed and I know using widget renders the rest of the fields and labels so what can I use in lieu? I tried

```
{{  form_start(edit_form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}

    {{ form_row(edit_form.orgName, {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-md-2'}}, {'label': 'Organization Name'}, {'attr': {'class': 'col-md-4'}}) }}
// blah blah more labels and fields


{{ form_end(edit_form) }}
```

This generates:

```
<div class="form-group'">
     <div><label class="col-md-2 required" for="company_nameofbundleorg_orgName">Org name</label><input type="text" id="company_nameofbundle_org_orgName" name="company_nameofbundle_org[orgName]" required="required" value="Computation Directorate" /></div>
    </div>
```

Update: I tried this:

```
{{ form_row(edit_form.orgName,  {   'label': 'Organization Name:'
            ,'label_attr': {'class': 'col-md-2'}
            ,'attr': {'class': 'col-md-4'}}) }}
```

I guess putting the "label" before the "label_atrr" matters. But why am I getting my class as "col-md-2 required".

```
<div class="form-group'">
        <div><label class="col-md-2 required" for="company_nameofbundle_org_orgName">Organization Name:</label><input type="text" id="company_nameofbundle_org_orgName" name="company_nameofbundle_org[orgName]" required="required" class="col-md-4" value="Computation Directorate" /></div>
</div>
```

As you can see it's not applying it to the `<div>` does not get applied. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using them separately like, `form_label()` and `form_widget()`?

Comment: Yes but as mentioned form_widget will render all fields and labels, there are a few I want to omit. That does allow me to format them the way I want but I have to include all the fields and labels.

Comment: I think I might have to do something like extending the "form_div_layout.html.twig", like this  [link](http://www.yewchube.com/2011/08/symfony-2-bootstrap-css-form-templates/)

Comment: If you want to include bootstrap as it is in your forms, Symfony ships with a theme designed to be used with bootstrap - [read here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme). If you want to render custom html for specific form - then yes. Creating a form theme for this particular form is also an option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might not be the best solution. I still think modifying the "form_div_layout.html.twig" is probably the best stratgey. A faster solution in my case is to just put

```
<div class="hidden">
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.orgFax) }}
    </div>
```

to not show the one field I do not want to display. If your interested in modifying the "form_div_layout.html.twig" it is located in /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/ and [here](http://www.yewchube.com/2011/08/symfony-2-bootstrap-css-form-templates/) is a good source for modifying it.

Comment: No. Do not edit files located in `vendor` directory. In a future update your changes would be wiped out. Instead, create empty twig file, then extend the template you want to modify and add you changes. And last, either add this template in your configuration (if you want to include it in every form) or include it only in those forms you want to change. [What are form themes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes)

Comment: I never said to edit the file directly. I even provided a link which explains exactly what you posted. I provided the locationof the files so you could see how and what you could extend.@Artamiel